# Is there a semantic equivalent of th for ul?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

```
<table>
<tr><th>Tags</th></tr>
<tr><td>c#</td></tr>
<tr><td>java</td></tr>
<tr><td>php</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is there a semantically equivalent way to express the `th` when using a `ul`?

```
<ul>
<li><h1>Tags</h1></li> <!-- this isn't really a list item -->
<li>c#</li>
<li>java</li>
<li>php</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's always:

```
<h1>Tags</h1>
<ul>
    <li>c#</li>
    <li>java</li>
    <li>php</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This might be ok, but I can't express a css rule like `table th { color:red; }` because the `h1` and `ul` are completely disassociated. there's no semantic relationship between them either

Comment: You can always use classes. There's a little semantic meaning there, and to me it's better than nothing.

Comment: Use section, nav, or something along those lines (the specific choice would depend on what the list is for).

Answer (score 3):

What about [definition lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element)?

Comment: +1 for (in my opinion) the correct answer but [I pity the fool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._T) who uses w3schools - http://w3fools.com/ :-)

Comment: Definition lists aren't really intended for "A heading and a list", but for "A series of terms and their definitions". If you only have one `<dt>` then you're probably doing it wrong.